# Collaborative image collection and annotation

Tags: windows, web-apps, images, knowledge-organization

I am looking for a collaborative way of collecting and annotating images, with a low cost of entry for users.
The use case I have in mind is as follows:

Together with a few friends I am interested in a certain topic. We encounter images related to that topic and would like to store it somewhere, add the source, tag it with keywords, and be able to retrieve the images + tags + source easily later. We currently use a shared WhatsApp group, but retrieving images with the related information is quite terrible.

Requirements

- Multi-platform (mobile and Windows at least)
- Very easily accessible
- Retrieval of images possible in a common format (e.g. storing keywords in the IPTC keywords field and the source in the IPTC description)

### Things I've tried

- [Tropy](https://tropy.org/), but [collaboration is not supported](https://docs.tropy.org/other-features/collaboration)
- [Pinterest group boards](https://help.pinterest.com/en/article/group-boards), but the images + annotations are impossible to get out.
- Google Forms, but using image uploads requires that the users are signed into Google (not always the case)

Comment: Hi Saaru.  I'm cleaning up some tags, and as part of that process, I noticed this question.  You mentioned that you want "mobile and Windows at least".  For this reason, I added the `Windows` tag.  By "mobile" do you mean a typical Android/iOS/other app, or a web-app (an app that runs within a web browser), or either?

Comment: Thanks for cleaning this up, either would be fine.

Comment: I've been investigating the same question since 2021 within exiftool's and Google's communities and found no available solution yet. There are many online communities in social networks dedicated to generating and sharing infographic materials, but none seems to have a necessary technical expertise to tackle the problem. I believe that due to copyright nature of such materials a higher preference must be given to platforms built on IPFS. Everyone seems to forget that Web 3.0 must be semantic, not just decentralised.